# Search for a word in files mentioned in a filelist

Tags: unix, search, filter

I have a set of files whose paths are stored in another files called filelist. I want to search for a word, for example "check", in all the files mentioned in filelist. Please suggest a way to do it.

Comment: look into `grep` and `xargs`.. or use a simple `while loop` and `grep`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
grep "check" $(cat filelist)
```